# Is there a command for creating a new Controller using Symfony framework?

Tags: php, symfony

I am studying right now the Symfony 4. I am trying to familiarize myself to this framework. For example in Laravel there's php artisan make:controller PhotoController..

NOTE: I tried

```
php app/console generate:controller or
php app/console generate:controller <name>
```

It gives me an error

```
Could not open input file: app/console
```

When I tried this

```
php bin/console generate:controller or php bin/console generate:controller <name>

It gives me an error "There are no commands defined in the generate namespace"
```

Question: Is there any command that will create a controller with method so that I wont type any more

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
```

Comment: that is `php bin/console generate:controller` for generate controller not app/console

Comment: Actually I tried it also but it gives me also an error "There are no commands defined in the generate namespace"

Comment: use which version of symfony?

Comment: are sure you are in the root of the symfony project?
this error occur when  php cant find `console`

Comment: I didnt specify the version of my app. I think it's the default? Because I just followed the instruction given. composer create-project symfony/skeleton symfony

Comment: Yes im sure im in the root of my symfony project. c:\xampp\htodcs\symfony

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is such command, instead of SymfonyGeneratorBundle use MakerBundle for Symfony 3.4/4.0 now, Generator is deprecated and as I know not maintained anymore, basic usage:

```
bin/console make:controller
```

More [here](https://symfony.com/blog/introducing-the-symfony-maker-bundle)

Comment: I downloaded the file of maker bundle.... in the github (https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle) where should I put those files

Comment: You don't need to "download" them, just use composer command and Flex will automatically add dependencies for your project:

composer require symfony/maker-bundle

See list of available projects for Flex here: symfony.sh

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
app/console
```

try

```
php app/console
```

here is doc [Generating a New Controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_controller.html)

Comment: you are using symfony4, so I think there is no option to generate a controller yet

Answer (score 1):

For generation controller `bin/console generate:controller`, you need to have installed sensio/generator-bundle, but as I know it doesn't work with Symfony 4 now. Try to use `bin/console` for getting available commands.

Comment: I just checked it, it doesnt have any generate:controller.

Comment: Sure, because this bundle does not support Symfony 4. It also does not support the new bundle-less directory structure as created by Symfony Flex. Use the Maker bundle instead.  https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle and Symfony docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html

Answer (score -1):

There are **two ways** to create a new controller in **Symfony**

1 php bin/console make:controller UserController

2 symfony console make:controller UserController

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Is there any difference between this answer and the one by Generwp posted five years ago?